# How to increase scroll amount/speed on brave browser?

Tags: scrolling, mouse-scroll, brave

I have HW acceleration, and threaded scrolling available. The scroll works smooth and looks great but it's quite short, meaning I have to scroll quite more than I'd like to reach the end of a page. How do I increase the scroll amount? (not speed, although I might assume increasing speed would increase the scroll amount, but that's not what I'm looking for).

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution is to use an extension for scrolling. I installed "Chromium Wheel Smooth Scroller" extension which solved the same issue for me. Another extension for scrolling could also work. If the extension does not work, it may be because it may need a restart of the browser.

You can install extension for the Brave from the [Chrome Web Store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/category/extensions) . Here, you can search for an extension (i.e Chromium Wheel Smooth Scroller), and once found, install it by clicking `Add to Chrome` on top-right of the page. Pay attention to the permissions the extension wants.

Comment: Good start.  maybe you could add some explanation on how to install such extension.